# IdentityServer4 Google sign callback doesn't include "IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme" cookie

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4, google-signin

I have an IdentityServer4 identity provider server. For the most part, I am using the template code from their repo. I am trying to add Google sign-in. I configured the GoogleSignIn in startup and added ClientId/ClientSecret.

When I don't configure the return URIs in the GCP project I get the following error from Google:

```
"The redirect URI in the request, https://localhost:44333/signin-google, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs..."
```

When I add the URI

[image]

Then as soon as I call `Challenge` I immediately get a failed callback from Google.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
{
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
    // Here, result.Succeeded is false

    // Rest of the method...
}
```

[image: Error screenshot]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have made it to the `Callback` method, then it sounds like Google auth has completed successfully. However, since the `IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme` cookie is not present, it sounds like you might have a little misconfiguration.

Once the Google authentication handler has completed, it will sign in using the auth scheme set in its `SignInScheme` property or the default sign-in scheme. It stores the claims from Google into a local auth method, such as a cookie.

What scheme is the Google authentication handler configured to use? If you're using the quickstarts, it may be using `IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme` rather than ASP.NET Identity's `IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme` that you are looking for.

Comment: That is exactly it. Changing the constant to `IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme` in the callback function solved it. Which one should I use?

Comment: It's up to you. One is from IdentityServer, the other from ASP.NET Identity. They are both intended for the same thing and configured with a short lifetime. If you are using the ASP.NET Identity auth cookie, then I guess it would be consistent to use the ASP.NET Identity external cookie.